My GitHub Pages embeds and images are not showing
I’m using the standard image tags and href attributes and ensuring the links are right, but it will either pop up as a white square or a 404 screen. Here’s my website if you’re wondering:
My website
It’s supposed to have an among us icon next to the This doesn’t exist project, and when you enter the This doesn’t exist is opened and the back button is pressed, there’s supposed to be a rickroll.
I tried fixing the bug by changing the paths, but didn’t work.
